# Can't fill 2d-array with sscanf_s out of a file

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, scanf

I search for my problem but haven't found an answer.
I try to read a table of double values from a file into an 2d-array of doubles in C++, but i can't get it to work.

The file is full of other junk i don't need and the table is parenthesized by "BEGIN TABLE" and "END TABLE". The Table has 5 doubles in a row with space delimiter and an unknown number of rows. So the File looks like this

```
junk
.
.
.
BEGIN TABLE
0.12145 0.23234 2.32423 1.32422 0.12345
1.34534 1.23423 5.21323 3.12313 1.22231
.
.
.
2.32422 3.23423 1.12345 4.34532 2.23423
END TABLE
```

So first I go through the file, search for the start and end of table and allocate memory for my array:

```
char sBuffer[100];
double** darrTable;
int iRes = -1;

    iRes = fopen_s(&pFile, strFile, "rb");
    if (iRes==0)
    {
        int ilines = 0;
        bool beof = false;
        bool bfound = false;
        //get number of lines for array allocation
        while(!beof)
        {

            fgets(sBuffer,100,pFile);                   
            if(strstr(sBuffer,"END TABLE"))
            {
                bfound = false;
                beof = true;
            }
            if(bfound) ilines++;
            if(strstr(sBuffer,"BEGIN TABLE"))bfound = true; 
        }
        darrTable = new double*[ilines+1];
        for(int i = 0; i < (ilines+1); ++i) darrTable [i] = new double[5];
    }
```

in an other code block i go through the lines again and want to readout the string, but it won't work

```
int ilines = 0;
bool beof = false;
bool bfound = false;
while(!beof)
            {
                fgets(sBuffer,100,pFile);                   
                if(strstr(sBuffer,"END TABLE"))
                {
                    bfound = false;
                    beof = true;
                }
                if(bfound)
                {   
                    sscanf_s(sBuffer,"%d %d %d %d %d",&darrTable [ilines][0],&darrTable [ilines][1],&darrTable [ilines][2],&darrTable [ilines][3],&darrTable [ilines][4]);

                    ilines++;
                }
                if(strstr(sBuffer,"BEGIN TABLE"))bfound = true; 

            }
```

it compiles and runs without error but all i get is an array full of 0.000000000 for darrTable. sscanf_s returs 1 witch suggest that 1 value was found, but thats all values are 0.

I use VisualStudio 2005 SP0.

Sorry for my english and thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use `%f` or `%lf` instead of `%d`. You are trying to treat `float` values as `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use C++ style

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

std::vector<std::vector<double>> ParseFile(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;

    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        if (line == "BEGIN TABLE")
        {
            while (std::getline(file, line))
            {
                if (line == "END TABLE")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    data.push_back(std::vector<double>());
                    std::istringstream ss(line);
                    double temp;
                    while (ss >> temp)
                    {
                        data.back().push_back(temp);
                    }

                    if (data.back().size() != 5)
                    {
                        // missing or extra data
                    }
                }
            }
            break; // END TABLE missing
        }
    }

    if (data.empty())
    {
        // BEGIN TABLE missing or there was no data lines
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast answer it works fine. I haven't worked with vectors so far. What does the line `data.push_back(std::vector<double>());` do? Does it add a "row"?

Comment: Yes. There is no 2d vector so you have to make a vector of vectors, similar to your array of arrays. Access like this data[y][x] or data[row][col]. That line adds a blank row vector into the top vector of row vectors. back() gets the last row vector we just put in, and adds the column data.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me from a lot of frustration.